# R double row filter by string

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I'm cleaning a dataset that doesn't yet have column names (so I'm working with indexes) and I'm trying to filter two columns of a df by piping the results of the first filter into the second and don't understand why the below doesn't work:

```
stripcols <- c("","Total+")

df <- df %>% 
  filter(!df[,1] %in% stripcols) %>% 
  filter(!df[,2] %in% stripcols)
```

Running this results in:

```
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Result must have length 46, not 58
```

This is easily worked around by running the filter twice, but I don't understand why this didn't work.

I'm also curious as to whether there is a way to do this with one filter command that is applied on both columns rather than two.

Comment: Instead of `df[,1]` or `df[,2]`, you should be writing the name of the column.

Comment: In additon to using names instead of column numbers, why not combine the two conditions, something like `df %>% filter(! first  %in% stripcols && !second %in% stripcols)`

Comment: At this point I don't have column names yet (still cleaning the data). I'll update.

Comment: The columns will have something as names, even if they're just automatic placeholders like X1, X2, etc. Beyond that, it's hard to help in more detail without a [reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with a representative sample of your data

Comment: Can it be that there are no parenthesis after !, i.e. !(df[1] %in% stripcols)

Comment: @camille Because I wasn't really looking for a solution to a problem, just curious if there was a reason, I didn't include any play data. I didn't realize that the automatic placeholders would work. I'm adding column names and will see if that changes anything. If not I'll add some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the error is that you are always comparing against `nrow(df)` rows regardless of how many rows hit the second `filter`. For instance:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=1:10)
dat %>% filter(a > 5)
#    a
# 1  6
# 2  7
# 3  8
# 4  9
# 5 10
```

The way you're writing it, you're doing

```
dat %>% filter(dat[,1] > 5)
#    a
# 1  6
# 2  7
# 3  8
# 4  9
# 5 10
```

For this first call, the number of rows that go *into* `filter` is 10, and the number of rows being compared *inside* `filter` is also 10. However, if you were to do:

```
dat %>% filter(dat[,1] > 5) %>% filter(dat[,1] > 7)
# Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Result must have length 5, not 10
```

this fails because the number of rows going into the second `filter` is only 5 not 10, though we are giving the `filter` command 10 comparisons by using `dat[,1]`.

(N.B.: many comments about names are perfectly appropriate, but let's continue with the theme of using column indices.)

The first trick is to give each `filter` only as many comparisons as the data coming in. Another way to say this is to do comparisons on the state of the data at that point in time. `magrittr` (and therefore `dplyr`) do this with the `.` placeholder. The dot is always able to be inferred (defaulting to the first argument of the RHS function, the function after `%>%`), but some feel that being explicit is better. For instance, this is legal:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  tally()
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#     cyl     n
#   <dbl> <int>
# 1     4    11
# 2     6     7
# 3     8    14
```

but an explicit equivalent pipe is this:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(., cyl) %>%
  tally(.)
```

If the first argument to the function is not the frame itself, then the `%>%` inferred way will fail:

```
mtcars %>%
  xtabs(~ cyl + vs)
# Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) : 
#   cannot coerce class '"formula"' to a data.frame
```

(Because it is effectively calling `xtabs(., ~cyl + vs)`, and without named arguments then `xtabs` assumed the first argument to be a `formula`.)

so we *must* be explicit in these situations:

```
mtcars %>%
  xtabs(~ cyl + vs, data = .)
#    vs
# cyl  0  1
#   4  1 10
#   6  3  4
#   8 14  0
```

(contrived example, granted). One could also do `mtcars %>% xtabs(formula=~cyl+vs)`, but my points stands.

So to adapt your code, I would expect this to work:

```
df %>% 
  filter(!.[,1] %in% stripcols) %>% 
  filter(!.[,2] %in% stripcols)
```

I think I'd prefer the `[[` approach (partly because I know that `tbl_df` and `data.frame` deal with `[,1]` slightly differently ... and though it works with it, I still prefer the explicitness of `[[`):

```
df %>% 
  filter(!.[[1]] %in% stripcols) %>% 
  filter(!.[[2]] %in% stripcols)
```

which should work. Of course, combining works just fine, too:

```
df %>% 
  filter(!.[[1]] %in% stripcols, !.[[2]] %in% stripcols)
```